# PHP CodeIgniter: Updating a dynamic array bound to an input field

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

What I'm about to show might be the most horrific code in existence, so be prepared. I'm new to PHP and received a CodeIgniter project. Here we go:

In my `edit_article` view, I dynamically generate `<input>` fields and make them accessible to the controller by posting them as an array, notice `name="pricelevel_checked_array[]"`:

```
<form id="form-work" class="form-horizontal" role="form" autocomplete="off" method="post">
    <!-- excluded code to display form content -->
    <?php
    $pricelevel_array = array();
    $count = 0; ?>

    <?php foreach($array_used_for_loop as $item_used_for_loop): ?>
        <?php $article_group_price = ""; ?>
        <!-- excluded code to fill $article_group_price -->

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <span class="bg-transparent left">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-init-plugin="switchery" data-size="small" data-color="primary" id="<?=$count?>"
                    <?php if($article_group_price !== ""): ?>
                        <?php array_push($pricelevel_array, 1); ?>
                        checked="checked"
                    <?php else: array_push($pricelevel_array, 0); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    onchange="groupprice_active_changed(this)"/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input hidden type="number" id="pricelevel_checked_array" name="pricelevel_checked_array[]" value="<?=$pricelevel_array[$count];?>">
        <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

As you can see, I fill that array with `1`'s or `0`'s depending on the value of `$article_group_price` (I get these values from the controller and originally the database).

It all works fine upon first loading the view and the array is filled correctly, but I can't seem to update the array when I check- or uncheck a checkbox.

I've tried to do this quick and dirty using javascript `onchange="groupprice_active_changed(this)"` where I would use the `$count` variable to change the index of the array, but unfortunatly that didn't work out since I only get one value and not the entire array:

```
<script>
function groupprice_active_changed(obj) {
  if($(obj).is(":checked")){
    alert("Yes checked");
    var input_value_array = document.getElementById('pricelevel_checked_array').value;
    console.log(input_value_array);
    for (index = 0; index < input_value_array.length; index++) {
      console.log(input_value_array[index]);
    }
  }else{
    alert("not checked")
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I best update this array or change my code so I can post the dynamic generated checkboxes to the controller? **Another problem is that I need the checkbox-id in the controller, even if it's false. And that the browser doesn't post an unchecked checkbox value.** So, just passing the checkboxes isn't an option.

I'm of course prepared to post more code.
Thank you

*Disclaimer: Please no steal*
**View**: [Complete code](https://pastebin.com/pjXrG5YR)
**Controller**: [Complete code](https://pastebin.com/HW4AwknT)

**Edit 1**: Changed 'php' to 'the browser' in the last section
**Edit 2**: Added as good as the whole code because filtering out will only make it more difficult.

Comment: It is not PHP that doesn't post a checkbox value. The browser does (or doesn't do) that.

Comment: Small detail, but edited it

Comment: Please try to increase your code as possible to test the specified problem. And please add a jquery tag here.

Comment: The checkbox inputs don't have a `name` tag. Do you want to make this work with JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: @toor I added the view and controller, can't post the entire project though. If the option is there, I rather use PHP, but if it's easier in javascript, I'll take that too. i just want to make it work :S

Comment: I think the good way is add something like   If ($_POST) var_dump($_POST);

Comment: You are also missing a matching bracket at the end of <input type="checkbox" data-init-plugin="switchery" data-size="small" data-color="primary" id="<?=$count?>" Add a > here

Comment: @Brad it doesn't look clean, but that `>`is actually closing as a `/>` 6 lines down. I'm actually modifying the `<input>` attributes depending on the state of `article_group_price`.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I have see used to make checkboxes behave better is to use
a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox. Put the hidden input before
the checkbox. If the checkbox is not checked, the value of the hidden input
gets sent. If you check the checkbox then the checkbox value overrides the hidden input. 
This works because only one of the values is sent. The browser sends the later one.

Take a look at the following example.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="off">
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" /> Foo
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php if ( ! empty($_POST) ) : ?>
    <div> Hello </div>
    <div>
        Checkbox is <?= $_POST['foo']?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: I've seen something similar in a different question but didn't quite get it, now I understand what you and they mean. Will give it a shot soon!

Comment: Am currently trying this but both values are being sent in my case as seen: `Array( [0] => false, [1] => on, [2] => false, [3] => false, [4] => on)` (middle of 3 checkboxes was not checked). However, I might still be able to make it work by sending the data twice and comparing the result, if the index is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually made the decision to drop the whole array approach and follow the KISS principle by passing my index to the controller. I use these indexes to only save the rows that are checked. Thanks to @ryantxr for showing me that I was overthinking all this.

### v_edit_article

```
<?php $index = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($array_used_for_loop as $item_used_for_loop): ?>
    <?php $article_group_price = ""; ?>
    <!-- excluded code to fill $article_group_price -->

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <span class="bg-transparent left">
                <input type="checkbox" name="group_active[]" data-init-plugin="switchery" data-size="small" data-color="primary" value="<?=$index;?>"
                    <?php if($article_group_price !== ""): ?>
                    checked="checked"
                    <?php endif; ?>/>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $index++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

### admin (controller)

```
public function edit_article($id) {
    // Excluded code

    $group_prices_active = array();
    if(isset($data['group_active'])):
        echo "<script>console.log('GROUP_ACTIVE ".print_r($data['pricelevel_checked'])."');</script>";

        foreach($data['group_active'] as $value):
            array_push($group_prices_active, $group_prices[$value]);
        endforeach;
        echo "<script>console.log('GROUP_PRICES_ACTIVE ".print_r($group_price_active)."');</script>";

        unset($data['group_active']);
    endif;

    // Excluded code
    $this->m_articles->edit_article($data, $id, $article_types, $group_prices_active);

    $this->session->set_flashdata('succes', $this->lang->line('edit_success'));
    redirect('/administrator/articles', 'refresh');
}
```